# Same database, same table, same query, but different where clause

Tags: sql, database, where-clause

I am a very basic user, so be easy on me.  Here's my *problem*, I am trying to get a count of the same column, but with different clauses.  I would like 2 queries from the same database/table joined into one. I'm sure it's simple...

## 1

```
Select count(inquiry_id) as 'Emails Tickets'
    , owner_rep
From sv_inquiry
Where logged_dt > '5/6/2013 0:00:00'
    and owner_grp in ('it service desk','corporate support')
    and it_source = 'email'
group by owner_rep
```

## 2

```
Select count(inquiry_id) as 'Tele Tickets'
    , owner_rep
From sv_inquiry
Where logged_dt > '5/6/2013 0:00:00'
    and owner_grp in ('it service desk','corporate support')
    and it_source = 'telephone'
Group by owner_rep
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that should work.

```
Select sum(case when it_source='email' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) emailTicketCount,
       sum(case when it_source='Telephone' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TelephoneTicketCount,
       owner_rep 
From sv_inquiry 
Where logged_dt > '5/6/2013 0:00:00' and owner_grp in ('it service desk','corporate support') 
group by owner_rep
```

You could also just add another GROUP by item to one of your original queries on the it_source field.